# (LibreOffice] Bootstrap variable for opening file in "Slide Sorter" tab

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-impress

I want to open LibreOffice Impress files such that LO starts with the 'Slide Sorter' tab on top (selected?) rather than the "Normal" tab.

I am using linux and would like to do this using the command line (rather than say setting this as a user preference).  I can't find any documentation on how to indicate what tab to start on.

I do know that the linux command  `$ libreoffice --help` mentions the use of

```
-env:<VAR>[=<VALUE>] Set a bootstrap variable. For example: to set
                       a non-default user profile path:
                       -env:UserInstallation=file:///tmp/test
```

This seems like a promising option. However, I can't find any kind of list of possible values for bootstrap variables `<VAR>` nor the possible values for `<VALUE>` for these bootstrap variables.

Can someone either help me open Impress files so they start with the "Slide Sorter" tab as the selected tab or, perhaps, help me find the possible variables and values for the `-env` command line option?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.